# How to get visitor email without asking?

Tags: javascript, php, email, cookies

O.K, recently there is something annoying me:

I visit some page, scroll it a little bit, and then exit this page.

After a couple of minutes, somehow, my Gmail inbox "by magic" receives an email from this exactly page, the problem is that I haven't gave them my email, how did they get it?

Seriously, how do they do that? I wanna Know this because I want to do the exactly same thing.

My primary guess is that somehow they get my currently Tabs title, and just use some kind of Script to get my email based on some REGEX, 'cause, for example, GMail Tag is just like this: || *variable title based on where you are - myemailaddress@domain.something - Gmail* ||

So do Hotmail/Outlook:

|| *variable title based on where you are - myemailaddress@domain.something ||

Is there any other way to get those addresses? Maybe by cookies?

Comment: I"d say that this is hijacking and might be even illegal. Probably through some JS script - which is not legit.

Comment: This, as far as I am aware, is not possible. You either have a browser  add-on or a piece of malware installed that does this.

Comment: I would love to visit the website. Do you have a link @Bruno?

Comment: Of course, this is the page: http://www.palaciodaarte.com.br I visited, add somethings to the Cart, and left the page.

Comment: I was able to track the tool that offers this kind of resource, its called, ShopBack, here is the page: https://www.shopback.com.br/email-remarketing.html

Comment: Were you logged in to the site when you abandoned your cart or did you choose cart items from a link in you email?

Comment: Not at all, just added something to my cart, not logged, not even have an account on that site, didn't filled any forms or any search boxes with my email/name. I'm saying there is something going on here. The tool site (shopback), did just the same thing, sent me an email, just after I leave, the same standars. I don't get the reason for so many downvotes, it's not a noob question, this is real guys.

Comment: I'm also trying to find out how this ShopBack works...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the user's email address from the browser.

Either you have provided that site with your address and forgotten about it or they are getting it from a third party which has your address (e.g. you may have granted permission for a site to access your identity on Facebook and then that site may be providing an advertising plugin that the site you later visited is using and then sharing your contact details).

Comment: I'm not dumb man, I saying I've never visited this page before, and they have no way to have my email. I not a regular user, or a guy who just started on the web. I have 6 years of experience, focused on front-end & digital marketing. I understand a lot of people do some dumb questions every single day, I'm telling you, I'm not one of those.

Comment: @BrunoRochaTeixeira — You said it was via shopback.com.br/email-remarketing.html  … which appears to be doing exactly what I suggested in the second half of the last paragraph of this answer.